# How to migrate from React Native app to a react-native module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've created a react native app with react-navigation (is just a react-native code won't needed to develop in a specific platform) is a very short app with 3 screens to list info from an API.
This is working as registered application.

Now what I want to do is use my app  as an imported component to be integrated from another react-native app ().

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# AnotherApp.js

import React from 'react';
import { MyModuleFlow } from 'my-module-flow';

const AnotherApp = () => {
  return (
    <MyModuleFlow
      param1={someValue}      
      onSuccess={data=> {
        console.log('success', data);
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default AnotherApp;
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# index.js

import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import AnotherApp from './AnotherApp.js'
import { name as appName } from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => AnotherApp);

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What should I do to migrate my project? my app has now some linked dependencies, I don't have any idea what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the solution by myself looking at [bob library from the community](https://callstack.com/blog/bob-the-react-native-library-builder)
What I had to do was setup the project as js-module to be build,

- native folders as ios and android wouldn't be needed anymore, so I removed those
- *bob init* (following the interactive cli)
- move all dependencies to devDependencies, and set

```
"peerDependencies": { 
  "react": "*", 
  "react-native": "*"
}
```

- if you are using tsx like me, then run *tsc --noEmit* and fix all the warnings
- *yarn* (will exec *bob build*, force it otherwise)
- next steps, add an example folder -> all the info to do that is [here](https://callstack.com/blog/adding-an-example-app-to-your-react-native-library).
- if you have doubts use this repos as guide: [react-native-tab-view](https://github.com/satya164/react-native-tab-view) [react-native-paper](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper)
- finally the bob build gave me the module wanted with the size I've expected 100kb and that's it
- There is a special module to handle release (publish to npm, change the package version, tag branches, etc) release-it.

Hope that someone find this useful

Comment: OH I forgot, all those linked dependencies will have to be linked from the example app and the developer consumer of the library will need to do the same. Just be sure to add the right steps in a clear way in the readme.

Answer (score 1):

You should create an npm module and publish it. It will bundle all your files and will push it to npm. Then you can import your modules anywhere.

This is what i follow: https://medium.com/@KPS250/publishing-react-native-modules-to-npm-40d2c4878a8e

Comment: I will be testing this option today, not sure if works due to the linked dependencies as gesture-handler, react-native-screens plus some fonts added, all of this are involved in the /android and /ios folders to behave as an app, and if I publish this like a module then ..should not change native code from project to behave as a module? it will not bring any issues? I'm just hoping that the bundle works within another app no matter if the module was in effect another app that now is imported.
Thanks for the answer!